# Android notification append content on update

Tags: android, notifications, append

I have made an android app (Android Studio / Java) that checks a website for content and stores it in an sqlite DB. If new content is fetched that is not stored in DB, it shows a notification with the new content for user to notice.

That's working fine, although if user does not read/open/dismiss that notification, the next notification will update current one and replace its content with new data. This is wanted behavior, because I don't want the user to receive many notifications for the same thing, so I'm using the same notification id.

This introduces a problem though, if user checks the notification now, he will see the second fetched data, but won't be aware of the existence of the first fetched data.

So, what I'm trying to do is to append to the notification's content, so that both first and second fetched data are shown.
I tried the ["inboxStyle" notifications](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle) that allow for new lines to be added, but it seems to be working only for setting many lines at the time notification is created and not for appending lines to an existing notifications.

I know that I can do that by storing what user has seen and what not, whether a notification was opened, etc, but this seems too much hassle for a simple thing, there must be an easier way to achieve it.

The expected behavior would be to either be able to append the message of existing notifications, or be able to fetch the message of an existing notification (by id) and then manually append to it and push the updated notification.

If that's not clear enough, the expected outcome is:

1. Issue the first notification with message "Test message 1"
2. Issue second notification using the same notification-id with message "Test message 2" that would NOT overwrite "Test message 1" but rather keep that message and append to it, so that the notification's message would now be "Test message 1 {newline-here} Test message 2" (or even better reversed so that the last message is shown on top).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution myself. I managed to do something that works but I'm quite sure there are other elegant solutions : I'm checking whether or not similar notification has been displayed. If so, I get the previous content and append it to the new notification content before publishing.

First, make sure that the notifications you want to assemble have the same uniqueID

This way, when you receive your 2nd, 3rd notification, you can easily match the one you are creating with the ones already displayed.

Note : This code works only on API 23 and higher.

```
String message = null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    StatusBarNotification[] notifications = mNotificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
    for (StatusBarNotification notification: notifications) {
        if (notification.getId() == uniqueID) {
            // You have a match
            Bundle extras = notification.getNotification().extras;
            message = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT).toString();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The easy part : Now that you have the previous notification text, you have to append it to the new notification text before publishing

```
String newMessage = message + remoteMessage.getData.get("text");
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),
                channelID)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(newMessage))
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText(notification.getMessage())
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```